# Try Catch doesn't work Firebase Storage [Unity ]

Tags: c#, firebase, unity-game-engine, firebase-storage

I have been trying to check if an image exists in the Firebase storage. As per documentation only way to do that is to check for exceptions

```
try
{
    bookImageRef.GetDownloadUrlAsync().ContinueWith(task =>
    {
        Debug.Log(task.Result);

        if (task.IsFaulted || task.IsCanceled)
        {
            Debug.LogError("Download URL: " + task.Result);
            // use default.png

            // ... now download the file via WWW or UnityWebRequest.
        }
        else if (task.IsCompleted)
        {
            Debug.Log("Download URL: " + task.Result);
            //   GetBookImageFromDB(Productcode, out _image, ImageDownloadLocDetails.DownloadDefault);
        }
    });
}
catch (Exception e)
{
    Debug.Log(e);
}
```

**Executed** the code doesn't trigger either of the **'if' statements** or t**he catch method**

It simply logs

> StorageReference gs://titlez-fae89.appspot.com/bookpics/prod123.png
>   GetDownloadUrl. failed Not Found.  Could not get object  Http Code:
>   404.

**Note** I tried both *StorageException* & *Exception* . Nothing seems to work

This is my first time posting on stackoverflow and I have heard its as brutal as Game Of thrones.

So kindly don't mind if my question is too vague and please feel free to let me know if I made it difficult to understand my query

Thanks & regards

Comment: Does it not reach `if (task.IsFaulted || task.IsCanceled)` at all? What happens when you step through thecode with the debugger?

Comment: If you need to catch exceptions inside of an async method, you either need to [`await` on that task](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ptorr/2014/12/10/async-exceptions-in-c/) or hold a reference to the `Task` object and then check its [`Exception` property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.task.exception?view=netframework-4.7.2).

Comment: @Stijn Its going inside try catch . It starts at bookImageRef.GetDownloadUrlAsync().ContinueWith then jumps to catch. But doesn't go inside catch method

Comment: @Foggzie Tried await but it needs to have async to be defined which couldn't be done as I am using Firebase Internal function. 2. I tried getting refernce . but its acting very strange some times it goes insde the if(isFaulted) , sometimes comes out of the task  and executes one line of command before returning . Could you point in how I can set it up properly . Thanks